# Custom Top AND Bottom Navigation Bars

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Is there examples of using custom top AND bottom navigation bars on one Activity page in Android Studio?

Comment: not sure what kind of navigation bars you are looking for but you can find material design examples [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/)

Comment: Basically three right-justified icons on top and bottom. Like a head, a box and a gears icon on top and any three for the bottom.

Comment: I'd suggest using "Bottom Navigation" and "Top App Bars" from the link I shared above.